# Can't interact with an object during a second pass

Tags: python

I've run into a strange problem while writing some code for my personal use.  I'll let my code do the talking...

```
def getValues(self, reader):
    for row in reader:
        #does stuff

    return assetName, efficiencyRating

def handleSave(self, assetName, reader):
    outputFile = open(self.outFilename, 'w')

    for row in reader:
        #does other stuff

    outputFile.close()
    return

def handleCalc(self):
    reader = csv.reader(open(self.filename), delimiter = ',', quotechar = '\"')

    assetName, efficiencyRating = self.getValues(reader)

    self.handleSave(assetName, reader)
```

This is just a portion of the code (obviously).  The problem I'm having is in `handleSave` trying to loop through `reader`.  It doesn't appear to ever enter the loop?  I'm really not sure what is happening.  The loop in `getValues` behaves as expected.

Can someone explain what is happening?  What have I done wrong?  What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you've iterated through an iterator once, you can't iterate through it again.

One way you can solve this is before you call `handleSave`, rewind the file and create a new reader:

```
f = open(self.filename)
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')

assetName, efficiencyRating = self.getValues(reader)

f.seek(0) # rewind file
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')

self.handleSave(assetName, reader)
```

Alternatively, you can read the data into a list:

```
rows = list(reader)
```

And then iterate through `rows` rather than `reader`.

As a side note, the convention in Python is for names to be lowercase, separated by underscores, rather than camel case. (e.g. `get_values` rather than `getValues`, `handle_save` rather than `handleSave`)

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't realize `csv.reader` returned an iterator.  I thought it was a list.  My fault for not doing more research.  :(

Answer (score 0):

The reader method of csv module, acts on the sequences and as you have iterated over it once in your getValues method, the sequence is already exhaused. Unfortunately, I don't see any better method than passing the sequence again.

Move the csv.reader into your methods and send

```
open(self.filename), delimiter = ',', quotechar = '\"')
```

Or create a file object each time or seek(0) to reset and send that as the argument to the object which will be handled by the reader method. That should help.